# Display filename only in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio tab

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

How can I just display the filename only in the tab?  Currently I'm getting the full path in the tab.

Comment: which tab?  also, is it version 2005?

Comment: Seems odd. I see just the filename on my tabs. The hover text does contain the full path.

Comment: My previous comment was for 2008. I tried this in SSMS 2005 and do indeed see the full path in the tab. I don't think there is any way (other than upgrading to 2008) to change this behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see here, make include filename true

[edit]..I misunderstood your question, there is now way that I found not to include the path[/edit]

[image]

Comment: Didn't you mean include databasename false? he wants to see the filename

Comment: pic doesn't match the text, I am saying to make it true..however the path is still there

Answer (score 1):

You have some options, but not enough to remove the path from the filename. Only for SQL Server 2008+

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Extension/add tiny clarity to SQLMenace Answer:

To show only the file name in the tab setting **Include File name** to **true** and the **rest** to **false** does the trick for me.
The full path shows in the tool tip when you hover over the tab.

I am using SSMS 18.8

Check below Screenshot with Tab examples:

[image]